# Having difficulty understanding how to remove some padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove padding using Boostrap 4 but having no success.

If you see this image it will make sense:

[image]

I am trying to remove the yellow padding that I believe comes from the fluid container.

I tried adding this:

```
 pb-0 mb-0
```

^ The above are classes to force ZERO padding/margin but still the extra padding is there.

It just feels like it is not in balance....

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid darkgrey">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">Section</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Title</li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: try `m-0 p-0` from `ol` tag

Comment: Use the box model under "Cumputed" tab in your webdev tools to see where it's coming from. Check all the descendent children this way too. ```<ol>``` and ```<li>``` both have built-in padding and margin.

Comment: It is due to breadcrumb class in ol remove it and the margin automatically removes. If needed to put the class then in the css put " .breadcrumb{ margin:0 !important;}"

Answer (score 1):

The margin seems to dissapear when you add the `mb-0` class to the `<ol>` element:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid darkgrey">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
              <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">Section</li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Title</li>
              </ol>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of default margin of ul and ol tag just add this css:

```
ul,ol{
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to mention, the correct way to write `0px` is just `0`. So in the case of the code you wrote above it would be: `ul,ol { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

Margin bottom added from class breadcrumb from bootstrap css you can remove it by using below css.

```css
ol.breadcrumb{
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```